# Scala - Object & Class

Tags: scala, generics, collections

I am beginner in scala. Got a doubt while trying to implement Collections..

```
class MyLinkedHashMap[K, V] {

  var initialCapacity = 16
  private var index = 0
  var map: Array[Node[K, V]]
  var head: Node[K, V]
  var tail: Node[K, V]

  class Node[K, V] {
    var key: K;
    var value: V;
    var next: Node[K, V]
    var before: Node[K, V]
    var after: Node[K, V]

    def Node(key: K, value: V, next: Node[K, V]) {
      this.key = key
      this.value = value
      this.next = next
    }
  }

  def MyLinkedHashMap() {
    map = new Array[Node[K, V]](initialCapacity)
  }

  def MyLinkedHashMap(initialCapacity: Int) {
    if (initialCapacity < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    map = Array[Node[K, V]](initialCapacity)
  }
  private def hash(key:K): Int = {
    return Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % initialCapacity
  }

  def put(key: K, value: V): Unit = {
    if (key == null) {
      return;
    }
    var hashIndex = hash(key)
    val newNode = new Node[K, V](key, value, null)
  }
}
```

The error I get at **Line no: 42** is

**Too many arguments for constructor Node**

However if I declare class Node in the object of MyLinkedHashMap I do not get this error. I wanted to know the reason for this error.

And I didn't want the Node class to be abstract, however the following error is raised when not declared abstract.

**Class 'Node' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member 'next: Node[K, V]' in 'MyLinkedHashMap.Node'**

Why is it neccessary for Node class to be abstract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error I get at **Line no: 42** is
>
> **Too many arguments for constructor Node**

Here, you are calling `Node`'s constructor with three arguments:

> ```scala
> new Node[K, V](key, value, null)
> ```

But here you define the `Node` class's primary constructor with no parameter list:

> ```scala
> class Node[K, V]
> ```

And there is no auxiliary constructor defined either.

So, the only constructor that exists on `Node` is the one that takes no parameters but you are calling it with three arguments.

If you want to call a constructor with three arguments, you need to define a constructor (probably the primary constructor) which takes three parameters, maybe something like this:

```scala
class Node[K, V](var key: K, var value: V, var next: Node[K, V])
```